# How to add a new column to a table with an unspecified amount of rows with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a table that allows you to add a column that will match the amount of rows to the existing rows within the newly added column.

I'm only attaching the necessary HTML to the post.

```
<table id="main">
    <th class="head"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></th>
    <th class="head"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></th>
    <th class="head"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></th>
    <th class="head"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></th>
    <tr class="alt" id="row">
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add New Row" onclick="addRow();" id="rowButton" />
<input type="button" value="Add New Column" onclick="addColumn();" />
```

And the JavaScript

```
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("main");
    var row = table.insertRow(7);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value">';
    cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value">';
    cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value">';
    cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value">';
}

function addColumn() {
    var table = document.getElementById("row");
    var x = table.insertCell(-1);
    x.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value">';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added dynamic rows and column code to your code.

A table object will have its rows or trs as `var rows = table.rows;` and you can find out about its cells or tds as `var cols = table.rows[xxx].cells;`

```js
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("main");
 var rws = table.rows;
 var cols = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rws.length);
 var cell;
 for(var i=0;i<cols;i++){
  cell = row.insertCell(i);
  cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value">';
 }
}

function addColumn() {
    var table = document.getElementById("main");
 var rws = table.rows;
 var cols = table.rows[0].cells.length;
 var cell;
 for(var i=0;i<rws.length;i++){
  cell = rws[i].insertCell(cols-1);
  cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value">';
 }
}
```

```html
<table id="main">
    <tr>
 <th class="head"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></th>
 <th class="head"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></th>
 <th class="head"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></th>
 <th class="head"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt" id="row">
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Value"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add New Row" onclick="addRow();" id="rowButton" />
<input type="button" value="Add New Column" onclick="addColumn();" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
function myFunction() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("myRow");
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
       var x = rows[i].insertCell(-1);
       x.innerHTML = "New cell";
    }
}
```

The problem was that you were only working with an ID tag from 1 row, where you really need a class name that can identify every row.

Here's a working codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOgZrE

Comment: This works, unless you add more rows and then attempt to add more columns from that point, it will only add to the original ones and not the newly created rows

Comment: It should still work as long as you continue to add the class name "myRow" to each newly created row.